# How to write Node.js binary stream from zip to an S3

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, buffer

I want to zip up files and dump the binary output right to AWS S3. I'm testing out my code first by making sure it can even write to a local ZIP file, which is not working.

```
function zipFiles(filenames) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const child = spawn(zipCmd, ['-'].concat(filenames));
    let buffer = '';

    child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      buffer += data.toString();
    });

    child.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
      // console.error(data.toString());
    });

    child.on('close', (code) => {
      fs.writeFileSync('testing.zip', buffer);
      resolve(code);
    });
  });
}
```

This results in a mangled zip file. I'm not really sure how to handle the buffer stream from `spawn` and assemble it into something that will work with `s3.putObject` and `fs.writeFileSync` (as a method of testing).

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
function zipFiles(filenames) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const out = fs.openSync('testing.zip', 'a');
    const child = spawn(zipCmd, ['-'].concat(filenames));
    let buffer = new Buffer('');

    child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      buffer = Buffer.concat([buffer, data]);
    });

    child.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
      // console.error(data.toString());
    });

    child.on('close', (code) => {
      fs.writeFileSync('testing.zip', buffer);
      resolve(code);
    });
  });
}
```